# Where are the program files stored on Android? ( not the .apk files but the actual installed files)

Tags: android, file, location, installation, default-programs

I recently rooted my vzw Droid3 and now I am trying to clean out the junk preinstalled programs.  I found the .apk files located at system/app, but I want to know where the installed files are.  As I understand it, the .apk file is a zipped installation file, not the actual program file that runs the program on the phone.  Am I correct? If so, where are the installed files?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the /data/dalvik-cache But I do not recommend to do this although I cannot explain why )